# How to replace chars/symbols in a process of writing of csv string/file with CsvHelper?

Tags: export-to-csv, csvhelper

I need to get rid of some symbols from each column in a row in a process of writing of csv string but I can't find such feature in `CsvHelper.CsvWriter.Configuration` nor `CsvHelper.CsvWriter.Context` or somewhere else.

As an acceptable for me workaround I tried to override method `ConvertUsing` of class `MemberMap<TClass, TMember>` and it didn't work correctly:

```
 public class CustomMemberMap < TClass, TMember >: MemberMap < TClass, TMember > {
     public CustomMemberMap(MemberInfo member): base(member) {}

     public override MemberMap < TClass, TMember > ConvertUsing(Func < TClass, string > convertExpression) => base.ConvertUsing(row => convertExpression(row).Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", ""));
 }

 public class CustomClassMap < TClass >: ClassMap < TClass > where TClass: new() {
     public override MemberMap < TClass, TMember > Map < TMember > (Expression < Func < TClass, TMember >> expression, bool useExistingMap = true) => new CustomMemberMap < TClass, TMember > (base.Map(expression, useExistingMap).Data.Member);
 }

 public sealed class CsvFileMapperAccommodation: CustomClassMap < Accommodation > {
     public CsvFileMapperAccommodation() {
         Map(m => m.Name).Name($ "AccommodationName").ConvertUsing(x => $ "{x.Name}");
         Map(m => m.ExternalKey).Name($ "AccommodationExternalKey").ConvertUsing(x => $ "{x.ExternalKey}");
         Map(m => m.Pension).Name($ "AccommodationPension").ConvertUsing(x => $ "{x.Pension}");
         Map(m => m.Category).Name($ "AccommodationCategory").ConvertUsing(x => $ "{x.Category}");
         Map(m => m.BuyingPrice).Name($ "AccommodationBuyingPrice").ConvertUsing(x => $ "{x.BuyingPrice}");
         Map(m => m.Margin).Name($ "AccommodationMargin").ConvertUsing(x => $ "{x.Margin}");
         Map(m => m.Price).Name($ "AccommodationPrice").ConvertUsing(x => $ "{x.Price}");
         Map(m => m.Quantity).Name($ "AccommodationQuantity").ConvertUsing(x => $ "{x.Quantity}");
         Map(m => m.Supplier).Name($ "AccommodationSupplier").ConvertUsing(x => $ "{x.Supplier}");
     }
 }
```

The object (which I try to map) contains a lot of properties so in an output I have about 300 fields per row, therefore, it's too complicated and not elegant to change manually the object data in the beginning and the value for each of the fields in the end. So I only try to map this object into a csv string hoping that it's possible to change it on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I think creating a custom `StringConverter` might meet your needs.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        var records = new List<Foo>()
        {
            new Foo {Property1 = "Property 1 with \r\n \\r\\n", Property2 = "Property2 with \n \\n"}
        };

        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<string>(new FooStringConverter());

            csv.WriteRecords(records);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class FooStringConverter: StringConverter
{
    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        var stringValue = (string)value;

        if (stringValue != null)
        {
            stringValue = stringValue.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
        }

        return base.ConvertToString(stringValue, row, memberMapData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I can't use specific logic for the property mapping .ConvertUsing(x => ...) in combination with custom StringConverter. The second one isn't applied in such case. So regarding to this solution, I have to choose if it should be a general custom converter or a specific one. I wanna both of them simultaneously.

Comment: How about if you put `.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "")` into an extension method and then use that extension method in both the custom `StringConverter` and `ConvertUsing()`.  That way if you make a change it will change both locations and you don't have to add `ConvertUsing()` to every property, just the ones that need extra formatting.

Comment: I got it, but in case of multiple fields/properties in which I wanna use `ConvertUsing()` I have to apply "copy-paste" practice of the extension method mentioned by you :(

Comment: Could you help me to override the method ConvertUsing, please? According to my opinion, it will be the best solution regarding this case.